# Upgrading codeigniter from 3.0.6 to 3.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hy, I have a site based on codeigniter 3.0.6 which I am going to upgrade to 3.1.0,
I downloaded the codeigniter 3.1.0 and copy my files (view, model. controller). I changed my routes.php, database.php and config.php.

I am facing an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Travels::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 77

Backtrace:

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\update\application\models\Travel.php
Line: 95
Function: __get

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\update\application\controllers\Travels.php
Line: 29
Function: all_des

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\update\application\controllers\Travels.php
Line: 41
Function: main_header

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\update\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

what should I do ??

Comment: well .. do u think you should upgrade via composer ?

Comment: or something like this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_301.html .. note the steps to upgrade there.

Comment: I have no idea how to upgrade via composer. I am new in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just replace the system folder with the new one.

Please refer to: [Upgrading from 3.0.6 to 3.1.0](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_310.html)